# How to use points data plot a colorful area?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have an array, `data`, in MATLAB just like following:

```
data = [0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1;
        0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1];
```

Numbers in this matrix stand for color. For example:

```
1 → red
0 → white
```

it not must be these colors, anyway,

```
different number → different color
```

I want to show on a two-dimensional plane.

I use `for` environment plot points (but these are discrete points, not a region).

[image: discrete points]

If I use `surf(data)`, it will have a 3D plot:

[image: 3D plot]

I can rotate this 3D plot and view above, just like:

[image: view above]

This image is what I want plot on 2D plane.

Is there any way to plot on a 2D plane directly?

Comment: What is wrong with `imagesc(data)`?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Well done.

Comment: A well drafted question [+1]

Comment: The third plot above is also the output of 'pcolor' which is basically the colors as if you had used a 'surf' command, but all the z values are 0. That's handy when you want to put 2D and 3D on a plot together.

Answer (score 1):

You may want a contour plot. You can get this by:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:size(data,2), 1:size(data,1)); 
contourf(X,Y,data);
```

For a more square and distinct look you could try:

```
scatter(reshape(X,[],1), reshape(Y,[],1), 1200, reshape(data,[1],1), 'square', 'filled'); 
axis equal
```

However, this solution requires that you to trial-and-error the size (1200) which will be dependent on the screen size of your plot.

Finally, in newer Matlab versions (R2017b+) you may use heatmap for these types of plots (https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/heatmap.html) E.g.:

```
heatmap(data, 'CellLabelColor', 'none')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll also check for heatmap-style solutions in case OP does not want interpolation between the dimensions.

Comment: Your code is good, but there is "transition line" between two colors, I think color should be changed immediately.

Comment: Understood. Countour plots make the assumption that the data is a sampling of a continously changing function. I think the heatmap function could work instead, but I unfortunately only have access to R2016b and it has changed: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/heatmap.html

Comment: So, not being able to check this; the syntax would be something like: 
heatmap(data, 'CellLabelColor', 'none')